# Get Id of One MySQL Table and Insert it into another table

Tags: .net, mysql, odbc

My Database is MySQL i have to get the Id in one of the table and insert it into another table using vb.net via odbc can you help me pls

Comment: is it helpful ? and dont forget to mark answer as accpeted if it resolve your issue

Answer (score 1):

for Sql server

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('tablename')
```

For mY sql

```
INSERT INTO foo (auto,text)
    VALUES(NULL,'text');         # generate ID by inserting NULL
INSERT INTO foo2 (id,text)
    VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'text');  # use ID in second table
```

MySQL would be the [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) function:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Comment: Make sure you lock the tables if you are using LAST_INSERT_ID()

Comment: I'm using the VB.NET Language and the connector is ODBC?

Comment: @user1197238  - i think that part is left on you .....you atleast need to do the code for that...or google the things for coding or go to msdn for more help

Comment: Insert into table1(id,name) Select '"  & LAST_INSERT_ID() & "'  is this correct

Comment: try "Insert into table1(id,name) Select  LAST_INSERT_ID()  " remove "

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO t2 (t1_id) SELECT id FROM t1
```

Add a condition to the select if necessary

To get the last ID using this query assuming AUTO_INCREMENT:

```
INSERT INTO t2 (t1_id) SELECT id FROM t1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

To get the last ID using this query assuming there's a timestamp record (e.g. created):

```
INSERT INTO t2 (t1_id) SELECT id FROM t1 ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 1
```

As per the comment from ypercube, if you are:

- performing a single insert with the same connection and,
- not using persistent connections and,
- not using connection pooling

then you can use LAST_INSERT_ID().

If you *are*:

- using persistent connections, or
- using connection pooling, or
- inserting multiple rows at once

then one of the options above is best

Comment: I'm using the VB.NET Language and the connector is ODBC?

Comment: @user1197238 Are you unable to execute a direct query?

Comment: I want to get the last id inserted in the database can you help me?

Comment: @user1197238 I've added some extra examples. To use LAST_INSERT_ID() you will need to prevent other inserts, e.g. lock tables/transaction

Comment: `LAST_INSERT_ID()` works per connection. Other connections can freely Insert on the tables and this connection will not be affected.

Comment: @ypercube Persistent connections/connection pools would of course break this. Also, LAST_INSERT_ID() won't give you what you want when multiple rows are inserted.

Comment: Well, you know that, I know that, perhaps you can add it in your answer, too, so the OP reads it :)